# wp_editor and WPAlchemy messes up tags when updating

Tags: php, metabox, wp-editor, wpalchemy

when using wp_editor, I paste my text in the visual editor. If I switch to HTML editor, all of my tags are there. So far, no problem. When I update the thing, all of my tags appear in my visual editor and in HTML, they become something like :

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;
```

If I update again, the tags appear on my page. So i'm stuck in editing my text only one time. If I update more than one time, the tags appear and everything gets messed up.

Anyone got a clue of what's appening?

I'm using that line to create the wp_editor:

```
<?php $metabox->the_field('shortText'); ?>
<p>
    <label for="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>">Text</label>
    <?php wp_editor($metabox->get_the_value(), $metabox->get_the_name(), $settings); ?>
</p>
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

The problem is with

```
$metabox->get_the_value()
```

It parses the code with the tags, wich then messes up everything.
Is there a way to parse the value in the HTML editor and not the visual editor?

ADDED SOURCE:

Input:

```
Faire des sorties de groupe et briser l’isolement. Venez vivre une activité entre gens qui vivent les mêmes choses, sentir la force du groupe plutôt que l’isolement.
```

Output (var_dump):

```
string(594) "<p><strong>Faire des sorties de groupe et briser l’isolement. Venez vivre une activité entre gens qui vivent les mêmes choses, sentir la force du groupe plutôt que l’isolement.</strong></p> <p><strong></strong>Le Regroupement vous propose des sorties de groupe pour faciliter le plaisir en vivant des expériences comme vivent les « autres familles normales ». Nos sorties sont dépourvues d’obstacles et se vivent sans les soucis de se faire identifier parmi le groupe.</p>"
```

And then the function get_the_value();

```
/**
 * @since    1.0
 * @access    public
 */
function get_the_value($n = NULL, $collection = FALSE)
{
    $this->_meta(NULL, TRUE);

    $value = null;

    if ($this->in_loop)
    {
        if(isset($this->meta[$this->name]))
        {
            $n = is_null($n) ? $this->subname : $n ;

            if(!is_null($n))
            {
                if ($collection)
                {
                    if(isset($this->meta[$this->name][$this->current]))
                    {
                        $value = $this->meta[$this->name][$this->current];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isset($this->meta[$this->name][$this->current][$n]))
                    {
                        $value = $this->meta[$this->name][$this->current][$n];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($collection)
                {
                    if(isset($this->meta[$this->name]))
                    {
                        $value = $this->meta[$this->name];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isset($this->meta[$this->name][$this->current]))
                    {
                        $value = $this->meta[$this->name][$this->current];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $n = is_null($n) ? $this->name : $n ;

        if(isset($this->meta[$n]))
        {
            $value = $this->meta[$n];
        }
    }

    if (is_string($value) || is_numeric($value))
    {
        if ($this->in_template)
        {
            return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
        else
        {
            // http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-function-called-by-embed-shortcode-direct
            // http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Embed/WP_Embed.html#run_shortcode

            global $wp_embed;

            return do_shortcode($wp_embed->run_shortcode($value));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // value can sometimes be an array
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when making use of the new wp_editor function on an alchemy powered metabox. I did some searching and turned up a solution that makes use of "html_entity_decode". Take a look at the reference here: https://gist.github.com/1838037

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: Great! That looks like my problem right here. I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: @Elggetto - You're welcome! That should work well for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`<?php wp_editor($metabox->get_the_value(), $metabox->get_the_name(), $settings); ?>`

to

`<?php wp_editor( esc_textarea( $metabox->get_the_value() ), $metabox->get_the_name(), $settings); ?>`

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried wp_richedit_pre(), which did not work either. Instead of getting the tags, I get their codes : &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;

Comment: I see two options here : Either run it into javascript when the page is loaded to take the tags and apply it to the visual editor, or be able to parse the result directly in the HTML editor and not the visual editor...

Comment: Hrmm, can you post the source for `$metabox->get_the_value()` as well as a `var_dump()` on the results of a call to that method? What meta box class are you using? These things should help to get a solution.

Comment: Done. As you can see, the bold text from the visual (naturally) gets parsed in the string. Now, I want this string to be reconverted to rich text. Before inserted into my wp_editor. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear. Can you paste the PHP code for the `get_the_value()` method as well as whatever method your meta box class uses for saving? What meta box class are you using? Without this info, it's really tough to say. Also, maybe try html_entity_decode($metabox->get_the_value()). (Though I don't like this approach, and I think whatever meta box class you are using is doing something strange).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I was out of town. So i'm using WPAlchemy for the metaboxes. I pasted the code in original post.

Comment: No worries! Unfortunately, I don't have a solution though :/  I did some searching, and found reasonably fresh link that suggests that it may be an issue with wpalchemy, and not your code: https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/issues/32 Also, I added the wpalchemy tag to your question, in hopes that it might get noticed by someone in the know with that library.

Comment: Well, thank you sir. It's exactly my problem... I'll continue searching. If it gets an update, i'll post it here.